# After Domain Change, 422 Errors When Uploading File with Nginx Upload Progress Module

Tags: http, nginx

I've had the Nginx upload progress module working for several months on various Ubuntu 8.04 servers, but on one of my servers I get 422 errors for every single file I try to upload (all files work on every other server). There's nothing in any of my logs that tells me anything.

This is the response that nginx gives me: "{ "state" : "error", "status" : 422 }"

The server configuration is identical to the other working servers.

But here's the **really odd part**: This only happens when I changed the domain name on the server (I changed the hostname, hosts file, postfix configs, nginx site configuration, and parts of my Rails app to all use the new domain, rebooted the machine, etc.) I grepped through the entire machine and found no trace of the old domain name anywhere. Once I change the domain back to the old one, file uploads work again.

Does anyone know how I might go about troubleshooting what's going on here? I'm completely stumped.

Edit:
I recompiled nginx with --with-debug, and here's some debug info from my logs that appears to be relevant here.

```
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 test location: "upload_progress"
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 using configuration "/upload_progress"
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 http cl:-1 max:10485760
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 generic phase: 2
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 generic phase: 3
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 post rewrite phase: 4
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 generic phase: 5
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 generic phase: 6
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 access phase: 7
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 access phase: 8
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 post access phase: 9
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 http set discard body
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 upload-progress: get_tracking_id
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 malloc: 080E7CA0:8
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 upload-progress: get_tracking_id found header: b3fec
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 reportuploads handler found id: b3fec
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 upload-progress: find_node b3fec
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 upload-progress: found node
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 reportuploads found node: b3fec (rest: 0, length: 168849, done: 1, err_status: 422)
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 http script copy: "{ "state" : "error", "status" : "
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 http script var: "422"
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 http script copy: " }
"
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 upload progress: state=1, err_status=422, remaining=168849, length=168849
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 uploadprogress error-tracker error: 0
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/0.7.67
Date: Sat, 20 Nov 2010 19:55:53 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 39
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache

2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 write new buf t:1 f:0 080DF1F0, pos 080DF1F0, size: 219 file: 0, size: 0
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:219
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 http output filter "/upload_progress?"
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 copy filter: "/upload_progress?"
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 http postpone filter "/upload_progress?" BFEB0A78
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 write old buf t:1 f:0 080DF1F0, pos 080DF1F0, size: 219 file: 0, size: 0
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 write new buf t:1 f:0 080DF160, pos 080DF160, size: 39 file: 0, size: 0
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 http write filter: l:1 f:0 s:258
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 http write filter limit 0
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 writev: 258
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 http write filter 00000000
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 copy filter: 0 "/upload_progress?"
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 http finalize request: 0, "/upload_progress?" 1
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 set http keepalive handler
2010/11/20 11:55:53 [debug] 8652#0: *13 http close request
```

Answer (score 0):

Logically if it works or doesn't work only depending on the domain name of the server and you aren't changing anything else at the same time and everything you wrote above is correct, then there are only three possibilities:

1. The old domain name is encrypted, compressed or compiled into a file rather than being present in plain text, which is why rep can't find it.
2. You are changing a config setting for the old domain name that you shouldn't be changing.  ie rather then forgetting to change a config that you should change, you are forgetting to *not change* a config that you shouldn't change.
3. You have a dependency on something external to the server which is expecting to see a request from or a request containing one domain but you are sending a different domain.

My best guess (combining points 2 and 3 above) is that you are using some external service (web service, authentication service or something similar) and have forgotten to update that configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry to be so late to ask, but can you explain point 1 in more detail? I'm just changing domain names in basic config files.